# Microsoft SQL Server on Mac

Tags: macos, wine

Has anybody successfully been able to run Microsoft SQL Server using Wine or another application like it (possibly Crossover) on macOS Sierra?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find out is look at the [Crossover web site](https://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/search/?name=SQL%20Server&browse=&app_desc=&company=&rating=&date_start=&date_end=&search=app) listing if each app is supported by Crossover which is the purchaseable version of Wine.

For SQL Server the answer is no - I think it won't even install.

So try running Windows in a Virtual Machine to run it or use another RDMS like Postgres or SQLite. An easy way to use a VM is to run [Docker for macOS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/) it includes (and hides a VM running Linux, Microsoft provide a Docker image for SQL Server with [instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-docker) for macOs

Answer (score 0):

There are some suggestions on [SQL Server on Mac](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62513/sql-server-on-mac) to run SQL Server in a VM.

However what is interesting is that earlier this year MS announced SQL Server to run on Linux.

[Announcing SQL Server on Linux](https://blogs.microsoft.com/blog/2016/03/07/announcing-sql-server-on-linux/#sm.0000oisajkvladbpqiq2qkvd2pt22)

And elsewhere

[Public preview of the next release of SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-vnext-including-Linux)

And also instructions for installing SQL Server via Docker.

[Run the SQL Server Docker image on Linux, Mac, or Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-docker)

So there are potentially other options for you.

---

Caveat - I have never tried any of this, nor do I expect to.

But SQL on Linux makes sense for MS given their cloud offerings.

Answer (score 0):

Have I been able to run MS SQL server on Sierra?

Yes.

Using Wine?

No.  Using VirtualBox

I have a dev SharePoint setup up (Active Directory, SQL Server, Web Server and Sharepoint Server) all running on VB on OS X and just recently upgraded to Sierra.

So, it works.

Now, the question is, do you want to use this for a test, or to put this into production?

If the latter, then it won't work because you simply won't have enough horsepower to drive the SQL server.  Remember, for SQL, you need lots of iops and this is not something the VB (and definitely not Wine) can give you.

Answer (score 0):

I am tried install ms sql 2000 using this [article](http://mynixworld.info/2012/12/22/ms-sql-server-on-linux-yes-it-works/) in wineskin. It works but no stable. Anytime lose network connection.
[image]

Comment: I also tried to install new versions of ms sql server, but it not possible because wine not have WMI and Active Directory implementation.